# Proxmox: Vlan interface not booting

Tags: interface, proxmox, vlan

I am making 2 vlans, Vlan10 and Vlan11, that will bridge to the virtual vmbr0 interface.

For some reason the Vlan interface is not booting. I tried to follow the information on the proxmox website about openvswitch.

I am following the bridge + internal ports + untagged traffic. The weirder thing is that Vlan 11 works while Vlan 10 fails to raise.

I have tried removing certain parts such as the ovs_extra part or the mtu part. I tried to google different solutions but could not find anything.

This is my interfaces file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens34
iface ens34 inet dhcp

auto ens32
allow-vmbr0 ens32
iface ens32 inet manual
        ovs_type OVSPort
        ovs_bridge vmbr0
        ovs_options tag=10 vlan_mode=native-untagged

auto vmbr0
allow-ovs vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet manual
        ovs_type OVSBridge
        ovs_ports ens32 vlan10 vlan11

allow-vmbr0 vlan10
iface vlan10 inet static
        ovs_type OVSIntPort
        ovs_bridge vmbr0
        ovs_options tag=10
        ovs_extra set interface ${IFACE} external-ids:iface-id=$(hostname -s)-${IFACE}-vif
        address 172.16.3.50
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 172.16.3.1
        mtu 1500

allow-vmbr0 vlan11
iface vlan11 inet static
        ovs_type OVSIntPort
        ovs_bridge vmbr0
        ovs_options tag=11
        ovs_extra set interface ${IFACE} external-ids:iface-id=$(hostname -s)-${IFACE}-vif
        address 172.16.3.60
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        mtu 9000
```

These are the error messages that I am getting:

```
Oct 12 13:46:54 pves3 systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Oct 12 13:46:54 pves3 ovs-vsctl[2756]: ovs|00001|vsctl|INFO|Called as ovs-vsctl --timeout=5 -- --may-exist add-br vmbr0 --
Oct 12 13:46:54 pves3 ifup[2710]: ifup: interface ens32 already configured
Oct 12 13:46:54 pves3 ifup[2710]: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/openvswitch: 1: eval: hostname-s: not found
Oct 12 13:46:54 pves3 ovs-vsctl[2795]: ovs|00001|vsctl|INFO|Called as ovs-vsctl --timeout=5 -- --may-exist add-port vmbr0 vla
Oct 12 13:46:54 pves3 ifup[2710]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct 12 13:46:54 pves3 ifup[2710]: ifup: failed to bring up vlan10
Oct 12 13:46:54 pves3 ifup[2710]: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/openvswitch: 1: eval: hostname-s: not found
Oct 12 13:46:54 pves3 ovs-vsctl[2872]: ovs|00001|vsctl|INFO|Called as ovs-vsctl --timeout=5 -- --may-exist add-port vmbr0 vla
Oct 12 13:46:55 pves3 systemd[1]: Started Raise network interfaces.
```

I know it says "hostname-s" not found but after fixing that in the interfaces file I got another error which said "cannot find vmbr0 as bridge"

Answer (score 0):

The way I got it working was creating another physical interface and another virtual interface that would bridge to the physical interface and then create the Vlans with the new virtual interface.